# Laravel @ After registartion, redirected to unexisting page (probably added by mistake, cannot find where)

Tags: php, laravel

After registration, profile is redirected to unexisting page with letter - **S**

mysite.com/s

but should be mysite.com/user/profile/

Probably, when I was touching some files, I add letter **S** somewhere

Any ideas, where I can check, where and how /s is called?

```
$redirect = $ref ?: '/user/profile/';
        Session::set('ref_url', null);
        return redirect($redirect);
```

In code looks Good, after success register, user is redirected to correct page, Where and How this /s/ is added?

It also, works like this:
1. Unregistered user clicks - Create new Order

2. System asks him to register an account
3. He creates an account, and automatically redirected to previous action - Create an Order
4. Link looks -> mysite.com/s/create/order

WTF? :(
Thnx in advance

**UPD: FIxed!! cleared cache. Lol :D**

Comment: Check your registercontroller.php and look for the redirect

Comment: it's ok as I can see :/

Comment: Check the trait RedirectsUsers and dd the variables

Comment: Try to debug the $ref variable and see what it have.

Comment: FIxed!! cleared cache. Lol :D

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to overwrite this:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/PATH';
```

In your RegisterController.